# Transaction locked after SQL*Net break/reset to client

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

This situation is happening a lot of times in our application, where after some database error the transactions get locked with **SQL*Net break/reset to client** status. Like this log bellow:

```
  SID  INST_ID STATUS   LAST_WAIT_S   S_IN_WAIT WAIT_STATE                     LOCKWAIT             SID_LOCKING L_INST_ID START_TRANS          CURS EVENT                           
----- -------- -------- ----------- ----------- ------------------------------ -------------------- ----------- --------- -------------------- ---- --------------------------------
  280        1 INACTIVE         .00     1550.02 * waiting (Application)        ***                                        2015-07-14-10.52.10    49 SQL*Net break/reset to client   
  366        1 ACTIVE           .00     1475.45 * waiting (Application)        000000009AF9E380 ***         280         1 2015-07-14-10.53.21    47 enq: TM - contention            
  318        2 ACTIVE           .00     1168.95 * waiting (Application)        000000009AF954A8 ***         280         1 2015-07-14-10.58.29    28 enq: TM - contention            
  154        2 ACTIVE           .00     1168.49 * waiting (Application)        000000009AFE6F50 ***                       2015-07-14-10.58.32    46 enq: TM - contention            
  288        1 ACTIVE           .00     1031.46 * waiting (Application)        000000009D99BE88             366         1 2015-07-14-11.00.49    34 enq: TX - row lock contention   
  114        1 ACTIVE           .00      975.45 * waiting (Application)        000000009D996598             318         2 2015-07-14-11.01.45?   46 enq: TX - row lock contention   
  108        1 ACTIVE           .00      939.54 * waiting (Application)        000000007A35DDD0 ***                       2015-07-14-11.01.57     7 enq: TM - contention            
  378        2 ACTIVE           .00      794.82 * waiting (Application)        000000009D997AC8             366         1 2015-07-14-11.04.45    19 enq: TX - row lock contention   
  322        2 ACTIVE           .00      637.51 * waiting (Application)        000000009B3DF6C0             280         1 2015-07-14-11.07.21    42 enq: TM - contention            
  179        2 ACTIVE           .00      551.71 * waiting (Application)        000000009AFA1488             108         1 2015-07-14-11.08.48    52 enq: TM - contention            
  322        1 ACTIVE           .00      547.60 * waiting (Application)        000000009AFBD2B8                           2015-07-14-11.08.52    44 enq: TM - contention            
  275        1 ACTIVE           .00      542.01 * waiting (Application)        000000009AFE6858                           2015-07-14-11.08.59    34 enq: TM - contention            
  374        2 ACTIVE           .00      517.92 * waiting (Application)        000000009D997BA8             318         2 2015-07-14-11.09.22    29 enq: TX - row lock contention   
  360        2 ACTIVE           .00      477.94 * waiting (Application)        000000009AFA31B0                           2015-07-14-11.10.01    17 enq: TM - contention            
  168        1 ACTIVE           .00      397.37 * waiting (Application)        000000009AFAE938                           2015-07-14-11.11.23    49 enq: TM - contention            
  187        1 ACTIVE           .00      352.04 * waiting (Application)        000000009D99C220             108         1 2015-07-14-11.12.08    36 enq: TX - row lock contention   
  166        2 ACTIVE           .00      282.10 * waiting (Application)        000000009D99AC10             154         2 2015-07-14-11.13.18?   25 enq: TX - row lock contention   
   20        1 ACTIVE           .00      270.32 * waiting (Application)        000000009A3EB828                           2015-07-14-11.13.30    18 enq: TM - contention            
  363        1 ACTIVE           .00         .00 * waiting (Idle)               ---                                        ---                    23 SQL*Net message from client     
  162        1 ACTIVE           .00         .01 * waiting (User I/O)           ---                                        ---                    28 db file sequential read         
  286        2 ACTIVE           .00         .01 * waiting (User I/O)           ---                                        ---                    23 db file sequential read         
  215        1 ACTIVE           .00         .02 * waiting (User I/O)           ---                                        ---                     8 db file sequential read         
  230        1 ACTIVE           .00         .01 * waiting (User I/O)           ---                                        ---                    21 db file sequential read
```

The error of the inactive transaction in the database was **ORA-00001: unique constraint violated**.

I've searched a lot and I didn't found any explanation of what is this error and what caused this lock-wait.

Comment: Sounds like your application just isn't handling the exception properly and that is stuck, rather than this being a database issue. You haven't shown any code for the connection, statement or exception handling so it could be doing anything, but possibly it's looping or waiting for some condition that is never going to be true because of the SQL error.

Comment: @AlexPoole, We use a SQLDirect component for Database access, we tried a lot to reproduce, generating the same error thousands of time and the lock-wait is not reproduced. Theoretically this happens a few times in production, so it's an specific situation that we are not understanding.

Comment: I think [this blog from Tanel](http://blog.tanelpoder.com/2008/04/10/sqlnet-breakreset-to-client/) describes your phenomen very good. And the *unique constraint violation* is there mentioned too.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Thx for the comment. I've read that post, and I've shown to our DBAs, but are still asking us how to avoid this locks. The main problem is that, generally the system works well when this kind of DML errors. The problem is that I didn't found any reason for this to happen once in a while to present to client

Comment: You can have a look  at this script https://www.crealoq.com/solved/Identify-Blocking-Session-Blocked-Session-Blocked-Statement-and-Locked-Objects-in-Oracle-DB can provide you more details about lock. Also you may need try to find the place where unique constraint violation happens as there may be some skipped TCL eg commit, rollback. Also are you using sequences as they may be out of sync.